# Parse JSON into an SQL query with AREL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, arel

I am building a rules engine, where some of the rules are logical predicates on top of lower-level "if-then" rules.

So in other words, I have a join table that stores matches between users and rules that these users were found to satisfy. Once lower-order rules are processed, the engine evaluates higher-level rules and creates new matches for users that satisfy them.

```
'user_matches':
+---------+---------+-----------+
| rule_id | user_id | rule_type |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 1       | simple    |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| 2       | 1       | simple    |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| 1       | 2       | simple    |
+---------+---------+-----------+
| 3       | 1       | compound  |
+---------+---------+-----------+
```

In the example above the Rule #3 requires users to satisfy both Rule #1 and Rule #2. User #1 matches this rule, User #2 does not.

Since I want to avoid hitting the DB multiple times, I need a way to turn such predicates into plain SQL queries that I'll then pass to `Arel::InsertManager`. Here's the gist of it:

```
UserMatch.select(UserMatch.arel_table[:user_id])
  .where(UserMatch.arel_table[:rule_id].eq(1)
  .and(UserMatch.arel_table[:rule_id].eq(2))).to_sql

=> SELECT "user_matches"."user_id" 
FROM "user_matches" 
WHERE ("user_matches"."rule_id" = 1 
AND "user_matches"."rule_id" = 2)
```

I am storing the rules tree as JSON:

```
{  
   "or":[  
      {  
         "and":[  
            {  
               "or":[  
                  21,
                  42
               ]
            },
            84
         ]
      },
      {  
         "or":[  
            168,
            336
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem, as you can see, is that these rules can be nested in an infinite number of ways. So I probably need a recursive loop here. Can't come up with one. Hope you guys help me out and give me at least a direction on how to parse this JSON pseudo-AST tree into an actual Arel AST tree.

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Turns out you can't use the same table twice in an SQL statement, see the answer below.

Comment: Also, I'd like a clean solution without concatenating SQL strings or `eval`ing strings with ruby code in them.

Comment: Having build a rules engine, my thought is that your question is likely too broad to be meaningfully addressed here. But, good luck - it's a big project!

Comment: @jvillian I ask for an algorithm to parse AST-like JSON tree into actual Arel AST object used by ActiveRecord to build SQL queries in Rails. Guess you didn't understand the question, it's not about rule engines per se.

Comment: Yes, I understand the question. And, it's very broad. *"how to parse this JSON pseudo-AST tree into an actual Arel AST tree that ActiveRecord understands"* is no small thing. I found building the engine quite rewarding, in the end. Hope it goes well for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `grouping` method is the way to create an Arel object that can be passed to `Arel::SelectManager`. Here's what I came up with:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe CompositeProcessor do

  MUTEX = Mutex.new

  before (:each) do
    @joins = json_tree.to_s.scan(/\D(\d+)\D/).map.with_index{ |item,i| i+1 }
  end

  def parse (tree)
    if Hash === tree
      raise 'There can be only one operator' if tree.keys.size != 1
      operator, operands = tree.to_a.first
      raise 'Operands should be in an array' if operands.class != Array
      raise 'There should be at least two operands' if operands.size < 2
      operands = parse(operands)
      query = operands.shift
      operands.each do |operand|
        query = query.send(operator, operand)
      end
      tree = UserMatch.arel_table.grouping(query)
    elsif Array === tree
      tree.map! do |item|
        case item
        when Hash
          parse(item)
        when Integer
          MUTEX.synchronize do
            id = @joins.shift
            UserMatch.arel_table.alias("t#{id}")[:rule_id].eq(item)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    return tree
  end

  context "being passed a JSON tree of predicates" do
    let(:json_tree) { { "or":[ { "and":[ { "or":[ 21, 42 ] }, 84 ] }, { "or":[ 168, 336 ] } ] } }
    it "parses it into valid arel AST" do
      expect(parse(json_tree).to_sql).to eq('((("t1"."rule_id" = 21 OR "t2"."rule_id" = 42) AND "t3"."rule_id" = 84) OR ("t4"."rule_id" = 168 OR "t5"."rule_id" = 336))')
    end
  end
end
```

This solution requires an instance variable: because each condition should be evaluated on a new self-join alias (t1, t2, etc.) we need to store how many joins we have yet to process.

The final SQL will look something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.user_id
FROM user_matches as t1 
INNER JOIN user_matches AS t2 ON (t1.user_id = t2.user_id)
INNER JOIN user_matches AS t3 ON (t2.user_id = t3.user_id)
WHERE t1.rule_id = 1 
AND (t2.rule_id = 2
  OR t3.rule_id = 4)
```

Comment: There's a good article describing a more generalized approach, but for me it is probably _too broad_ https://www.thegreatcodeadventure.com/composable-query-builders-with-arel-in-rails/